# Which stone of the Kotel is directly opposite the Kodesh hakodashim?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem, kotel-western-wall

"The Belzer Rebbe, Rebbe Ahazon, zatsal, when visiting the wall would search for a certain protruding stone. He would pray at that spot, explaining that his father, Reb Yissachar Dov, zatzal, had told him that this stone was directly opposite the Kodesh Hakodashim (Holy of Holies)." (page 7: http://ohr.edu/ohrnet/5759/bereishi/noach.pdf)

Which stone is it ? Do you have a picture of it or way to find it ?

Comment: In what year did Reb Yissachar Dov, visit the kotel to point out the stone?

Comment: Could he have been at the little kotel in the Moslem quarter?

Answer (score 6):

There is no stone on the exposed kotel which is opposite the kodesh hakadoshim.  However if you go to the tunnel tours there is a spot marked which is.

See this page for maps and pictures:

http://www.generationword.com/jerusalem101/38-western-wall-tunnels.html

Comment: Wouldn't the spot above the spot marked below also be opposite the Kodesh haKodoshim?

Comment: The spot above, is the middle of some building and is not open to the public.

Comment: @avi : I am looking for stone the Belzer rabbi was looking for. According to Rav Moshe Shternbuch, according to the Zohar also, the kodesh hakodashim is just behind the Kotel.

Comment: @ari How can the Zohar be talking about the Kotel plaza that is open to the public today?

Comment: The Zohar says that there will never be something build over the kodesh hakodashim. Rav Mosher Shternbuch concluded that it was another justification (besides the electromagnetic search of the site and the "hallows" behind the Kotel) that the kodesh hakodashim was behind the Kotel. He added that it was why Hashem let us only the western wall so we can face the kodesh hakodashim while praying.

Comment: Ok, well good luck. Does it have to be on the men's side?

Comment: @ari Then you got a problem. Hashem didn't only leave the western side of the temple mount... The other 4 sides exist too.

Comment: @double AA: he did for the jews. We use the western wall, didnt we ?

Comment: @ari Not sure what you're talking about. Jews use multiple parts of the wall now to pray at and have prayed at many, many different parts of it over the centuries. Whatever wall he's talking about in the Midrash, it isn't the retaining wall of the mountain.

Comment: I have never wrote about the Midrash. Shternbuch explain that Hachem made the jews use the western wall because it makes us daven in direction of the kodesh hakodashim. I think it was obvious in my message.

Answer (score 0):

The Belzer Rebbe, Rebbe Ahazon moved to Israel in 1944 but passed in 1957.  The western wall was off limits to Jews from 1948 until 1967.

Here is a picture from the side of what the Kotel would have looked like to anyone visiting the Kotel between 1944 and 1948.

[image]

I have looked at other images as well, and the only stone that appears to be protruding to me, is the one which is next to the large bush, about 7 stones up, and about 13-15 stones away from "close edge".  In the 1920s, the British "cleaned up" the wall, for the sake of it being a world heritage site, or something similar.

Other pictures from the era, do not show any stones sticking out, but one stone in particular is seen as being pushed in.  That stone can be seen even today, and it is easy to spot.

[image]

Comment: Yashar Coach for your answer ! Maybe the protruding stone was low, in the first range. We dont see these stones in your first picture.

Comment: @ari that is why I put in the second picture, so you can see the first row. There is the stone sticking in, but no stone sticking out.

Comment: Maybe one day a belzer hassid will see my question and give me the answer. Who knows.

Comment: Please [edit] in credits for where you got these pictures from.